# CardsLayout in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have taken a JPanel (say cardsPanel) and have set its layout as CardsLayout. After that I have added 3 cards on it (say card1, card2, and card3) all of JPanel type.

Now I want to get the topmost card of the cardsPanel whenever a user clicks on a button "Show".

So, How can I get the top-most card of the cardsPanel.

Answer (score 1):

The [CardLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) has four methods which might be of use to you.

- [first(Container parent)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#first(java.awt.Container))
- [last(Container parent)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#last(java.awt.Container))
- [next(Container parent)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#next(java.awt.Container))
- [previous(Container parent)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#previous(java.awt.Container))

The Container you pass in is the reference to the parent of your cards 1 to 3. So in the actionPerformed of the 'Show' button just use the appropriate method (first I guess?).

Comment: I think he wants to perform the inverse operation. I think he needs to pull the JPanel off of the CardLayout, which I don't believe is possible directly.

Comment: In either case, the questioner can specify a name in `addLayoutComponent()` and use `show()` or `removeLayoutComponent`.